# How to get daily maximum and average on Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a very simple set of excel data

Column A: Date & time (eg. 5/13/2016 00:00)
Column B: Response time (1.43212)

I currently have about 1 month of data (~2000 rows)

How do I calculate the daily average and daily max?

Thanks

Comment: Look into averageif and the array formula max(if())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have a header row and your data goes from A2:B2000.

In column D generate a list of dates you want the daily maximum for.  Lets assume your first date in in D2

In E2 adjacent to the first date you want to find a maximum for use the following formula:

```
 =AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B2000*(INT($A$2:$A$2000)=$D2),1)
```

Copy that formula down beside each date you want to know the maximum for.

Caveat:

For dates which you have no data, you will have a value of 0 returned.

For the daily average you use the following in starting in F2:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$2000,$A$2:$A$2000,">="&$D2,$A$2:$A$2000,"<="&$D2+1-TIME(0,0,1))
```

or you could do:

```
=iferror(sumproduct((INT($A$2:$A$2000)=$D2)*$B$2:$B$2000)/sumproduct((INT($A$2:$A$2000)=$D2)*1),"No Date")
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Date&Time" column actually includes "Time", you first have to create a new Column, that removes the "Time" from the "Date&Time" column, so you can have the "Date" associated (without Time). To do that you cau use the following formula:

```
=INT(A1)
```

The you can create a PIVOT TABLE, to create the aggregated columns (AVG and MAX)